# If a graph has a unique MST, then its edge weights are distinct. True or false ? Justify your answer.

Tags: graphs, minimum-spanning-tree

If a graph has a unique MST, then its edge weights are distinct. True or false ? Justify your answer.

Comment: You should first make some effort solving the exercise on your own.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is: not necessarily.

Counterexample: consider a graph that is a tree with all of its edges the same weight. Then the only MST is the entire graph and none of the edge weights are distinct.